# Request comments on a set of wrapper functions for signals API on linux

Tags: signals, posix, wrapper

Please feel free to comment on the accuracy / validity of the following wrapper source
for processing signals using the new POSIX sigaction API.  If you feel I'm doing anything wrong or potentially dangerous, chime in.

Note: syserr is a custom function not shown to exit gracefully.

Thx.

### wrapper begins after next line...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

static struct sigaction *
handle_signal(int sig,
              int flags,
              void (*handler)())
{
static struct sigaction action;
static struct sigaction o_action;

/* init the sigaction structs */
memset(&action, 0, sizeof(action));
memset(&o_action, 0, sizeof(o_action));

/* setup our signal handler function to call when it fires */
action.sa_handler = handler;

/* initialize the signal mask */
sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);

/* use the user passed in flags setting othersize init them */
if (flags != 0)
   action.sa_flags = flags;
else
   action.sa_flags = 0;

if (sigaction(sig, &action, &o_action) != 0)
   syserr();

return(&o_action);

}

static struct sigaction *
ignore_signal(int sig)
{
static struct sigaction action;
static struct sigaction o_action;

/* init the sigaction structs */
memset(&action, 0, sizeof(action));
memset(&o_action, 0, sizeof(o_action));

/* setup to ignore this signal */
action.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;

/* initialize the signal mask */
sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);

action.sa_flags = 0;

if (sigaction(sig, &action, &o_action) != 0)
   syserr();

return(&o_action);

}

int
block_signal(int sig)
{
static sigset_t mask;
static sigset_t orig_mask;
int ret;

sigemptyset(&mask);
sigemptyset(&orig_mask);

sigaddset(&mask, sig);

ret = sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &orig_mask);

return(ret);
}

int
unblock_signal(int sig)
{
static sigset_t mask;
static sigset_t orig_mask;
int ret;

sigemptyset(&mask);
sigemptyset(&orig_mask);

sigaddset(&mask, sig);

ret = sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, &orig_mask);

return(ret);

}

sigset_t *
get_signal_mask()
{
static sigset_t orig_mask;

sigemptyset(&orig_mask);

/* null in set arg means return current mask */
if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, NULL, &orig_mask) < 0)
   syserr();

return(&orig_mask);

}
```

Comment: This question lacks a question and belong on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: comment / question added to CodeReview...thx duck...did not know that this site even existed.

Comment: you are welcome.  I hope you find satisfaction there.  If I get a chance I'll try and follow up.